# How to setup SAPI with Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, sapi

I need to know how can I set up SAPI (Windows Speech API) with visual C++ 2010 express. I got to know Windows 7 comes with built in SAPI libs, and I am using windows 7. However, I downloaded SAPI 5.1 in case it is needed. MS instructions about setting up SAPI with VS is pretty old, which didn't work for me.

How can I set it up with VS 2010 Express, because I need to apply those settings to QT and proceed with my final year project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what do you know. I took code from your previous question, and removed the ATL stuff (ATL not supported on Visual Studio Express 2010). I was left with this

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sapi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        cout << "Succeeded" << endl;
        hr = pVoice->Speak(L"Hello world", 0, NULL);
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not succeeded" << endl;
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
    return TRUE;
}
```

I created a standard Windows Console Application project and used this code as the only source file. Compiled and ran it and it worked. It spoke! In a female voice.

I've done zero set up at all. So it obviously works out the box. I never knew about this library before.

I have Windows 7 and VS 2010 express.

Comment: errr...Thanks for the reply, but I do not get any sound!

Comment: did you select a project with "precompiled header" files? I selected "empty project"

Comment: precompiled header off (doubt it makes any difference however), empty project on. Maybe it's a sound driver thing? Outside my experience I'm afraid.

Comment: OK, I will check this with my other computer as well.

Comment: Yes! It works! No idea why it is not working in my Dell laptop :(. However, can you please tell me how to do this with QT  as well?

Comment: Sorry, know almost nothing about QT